# Get Month from Date in Log File

Tags: java

I have an input String formatted like this.

`96.7.4.14 - - [24/Apr/2011:04:20:11 -0400] "GET /cat.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 1243`

I know how to get the entire date from the string, but what would be the best way to just extract the three letter month code?

Comment: use a regular expression

Comment: agreed...regular expression

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following regex to extract the three letters month

[`(?<=\d{2}\/)(\w{3})(?=\/\d{4})`](https://regex101.com/r/5oa2ou/2)

What it does basically is lookbehind to find two digits and a slash and also lookahead to find a slash and 4 digits while matching three word characters.

---

Alternative, an even simpler solution, without using regular expressions, given the beginning of the string always contains the same formatted characters is the following

```
String text = "96.7.4.14 - - [24/Apr/2011:04:20:11 -0400] \"GET /cat.jpg HTTP/1.1\" 200 1243";
int firstLetterOfMonth = text.indexOf('/') + 1;
String month = text.substring(firstLetterOfMonth, firstLetterOfMonth + 3);
System.out.println(month); // Apr
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know that website existed either so that will help in the future.

Comment: I'm not sure how this expression will actually do what is asked.  It doesn't define a group around the one thing you want to get out of the string.  I guess maybe there's a way to use the other groups to get to what you want, but it's not the straightforward way to go.  Also, there's no need to do the "lookbehind" stuff or escape the forward slash. - you should provide code to show how this expression is used to provide the requested answer.  I'm a regex weenie, and I don't know how I could use your expression to get what is required.

Comment: @Steve is right - this answer is over complicated, and suggests regex practices that aren't necessary.  I agree that there's no reason to escape forward slashes.  I tried Steve's code.  It works with no such escaping.

Comment: @Steve the code works, I already had everything, I just needed help with the Regex. I ran in multiple times

Comment: I am referring to the expression, it is literally doing what I need it do do and pulling the months from the string...

Comment: @sbowde4 - if that's true of the original expression that existed when you approved it, I want to see your code.  I can look back at the edits.  This is a significant issue.  There are too many bad answers on SO that confuse people rather than helping them.  I'm just fighting to keep the information on SO of high quality. - it's fine for the answerer to ammend his answer. Once an answer is correct, THEN it can be upvoted and accepted.

Comment: Ok, yeah.  That second solution works if you can assume that the strings will always look like that, which seems like a fair assumption in this case.  I didn't have any problem with you're sincere attempt to help the OP.  I've just seen too many bad SO answers approved and never get fixed, so they remain as incorrect answers.  your answer is now technically correct (well, assuming that backlook stuff works, which I haven't ever had to use).  Thanks for fixing it!

Comment: both answer are helpful now ;) +1 for each one

Answer (score 1):

You can provide a pattern to look for the whole date:

```
private static final Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\d{2}\\/)(\\w{3})(\\/\\d{4})");
```

and then use a matcher to find the group with the three letter word (aka the month):

```
Matcher m = p.matcher("96.7.4.14 - - [24/Apr/2011:04:20:11 -0400] GET /cat.jpg HTTP/1.1 200 1243");

if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(2)); // second expression from the round brackets
}
```

Comment: No need to escape forward slashes or put groups around the other portions of the expression.  But yes, this works too!

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class x {

    public static void main (String [] args) {
        String data = "96.7.4.14 - - [24/Apr/2011:04:20:11 -0400] \"GET /cat.jpg HTTP/1.1\" 200 1243";

        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d{2}/(\\w{3})/\\d{4}");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(data);
        if (m.find())
            System.out.println(m.group(1));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Apr
```

Depending on the domain of potential strings to be matched, you could get by with an even simpler pattern, like just look for three word characters between a pair of forward slashes.  This is just an example.  I'm not proposing that this is the optimum expression for your needs.

Comment: We came up with basically the same solution at the same time.  :)  I believe you are missing an escape character for your forward slashes in your pattern though.

Comment: Ooops...sorry @Babyburger - was treating you as the other answerer - you don't need to escape forward slashes though.  They don't mean anything in regex.